# How to test whether each element in a column of values falls between values in two other columns?

Tags: r, dataframe, operators

This may be a very convoluted way of asking this question. I have a column of "results" that I want to test against statistics of previous results, namely calculated minimum and maximum values. If the value in the result column falls between the corresponding min and max values, I want to assign it as "1" in a fourth column named Within_range and if not, "0".
I have tried using relational operators (<,>)

```
df$Within_Range <- if(df$Result > df$Min & df$Result < df$Max){"1"} else {"0"}
```

and got this:
In if (df$Result > df$Min & df$Result < df$Max) { :
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

R did not seem to like that I tried to use multiple conditions, so I tried using between()

```
df$Within_Range <- if(between(df$Result,df$Min,df$Max)){"1"} else {"0"}
```

and I got this:
Error: Expecting a single value: [extent=20511].

Here is some example code:

```
Result <- 1:5
Min <- c(2,1,2,3,4)
Max <- c(3,4,5,8,7)
df <- data.frame(Result, Min, Max)
```

Apologies if this is a silly question; I am still new to R and hours of searching R forums returned nothing helpful... I am stuck.

Answer (score 1):

`between` is not vectorized for the `left`, `right` arguments.  We need comparison operators

```
df$Within_Range <- with(df, +(Result > Min & Result < Max))
```

NOTE: Change to `>=` or `<=` if the range should also include the Min, Max values

---

Also, in the first piece of code, the `if/else` is unnecessary due to multiple reasons

1. It is not vectorized i.e. it expects a input of length 1 and output a logical vector of length 1 (`df$Result` and other columns are obviously having `length` greater than 1)
2. TRUE/FALSE output from comparison operators are stored as `1/0` values.  So, we just need to coerce it to binary with `as.integer` or `+`

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The way you explained it makes much more sense now. This code ran, however the created column "Within_Range" contains only FALSEs which is incorrect...

Comment: @mika Please check your `Result` column type.  Is it numeric

Answer (score 0):

```
df %>% mutate(Within_Range = between(Result, Min, Max))

## OutPut
  Result Min Max Within_Range
1      1   2   3        FALSE
2      2   1   4         TRUE
3      3   2   5         TRUE
4      4   3   8         TRUE
5      5   4   7         TRUE
```